# Правильный запрос MySQL Oracle

Tags: c#, mysql

У меня есть сервер работающий с базой данных MySQL Oracle. Локальный хост установлен прямо на машине. Я сделал патч обновления, где уже у персонажей пресутсвуют способности. За каждое повышение уровней, дается по два очка способностей, которые Вы можете вложить в одну из способностей.

Проблема заключается в том, что есть уже персонажи довольно высокого уровня. И публично сказать им что они будут прокачиваться заново - не есть хорошо) Есть ли способ сделать как-то запрос в MySQL, чтобы через `UPDATE` взять и установить нужное значение очков способностей? К примеру, у персонажа 14 уровень: 14 * 2 = 28 очков способностей начисляется в поле персонажу такому-то.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `characters`;
CREATE TABLE `characters` (
  `account_name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `obj_Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `char_name` varchar(35) NOT NULL,
  `level` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `maxHp` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `curHp` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `maxMp` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `curMp` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `face` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `hairStyle` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `hairColor` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `sex` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `heading` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `x` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `y` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `z` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `exp` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `karma` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `pvpkills` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `classid` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `base_class` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deletetime` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(16) DEFAULT NULL,
  `accesslevel` mediumint(9) DEFAULT '0',
  `online` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `onlinetime` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `char_slot` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastAccess` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `skill_points` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`obj_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: А нельзя что ли просто для всех игроков получить нужное значение (уровень), а потом заново установить?

Comment: Если очки способностей так жестко привязаны к уровню, зачем вы их храните отдельно? Не проще ли вычислять их количество из уровня по этой же формуле на сервере? Или у вас планы развивать эту логику?

Comment: @Akina, я полагаю, что это все-таки MySQL. Пользователь по всей видимости добавил в название правообладателя ( правообладателем MySQL, после поглащения Sun Microsystems является также Oracle)

Comment: @МихаилРебров Я тоже так считаю, но мало ли... авторы тут сплошь и рядом лепят тег мускуля вообще на любой вопрос по SQL...

Comment: @aepot Думаю, что эти очки - расходуемые, и в существующей структуре автор решил хранить не назначенное количество, а оставшееся... ну это его проблемы. Я бы предложил наоборот - хранить количество израсходованных, а актуальное - считать из уровня и текущего расхода.

Comment: @Akina это тоже можно посчитать исходя из списка изученных навыков. 3НФ :)

Comment: @aepot Ооо... а вот необязательно. Это ж игра... и стоимость скилла запросто может быть функцией от имеющихся скиллов - а в этом случае для расчёта придётся лопатить всю историю от сотворения времён, если она вообще хранится.

Comment: Вы можете показать какие поля и в каких таблицах хотите изменить? Если там несколько таблиц, покажите все. Под "показать" я имею в виду либо код создания (CREATE TABLE), либо картинку, если для работы с базой пользуетесь утилитой с UI.

На словах у меня не получилось понять, что именно вы хотите сделать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дополнение

Автор вопроса сделал такое уточнение: "Потом умножить их уровни на 2 и мы получим очки способностей. И обновить через Update таблицу".
В такой формулировке вопрос-довольно простой. Пусть ulevel - это уровень, upoints - это очки способностей.

Тогда запрос `Update characters set upoints=ulevels*2;` как раз сделает нужное.

---

Я прочитал вопрос и список комментариев к нему.

По моему, сам подход у Вас - ведёт к проблемам для существующих игроков.

Давайте попробуем разобраться.

"Я сделал патч обновления"

А как Вы его сделали?

Информации очень мало, но, как Вы пишете - "где уже у персонажей присутсвуют способности"

С точки зрения базы данных - это **добавление** дополнительных полей в таблицу.

Ну, то есть, был персонаж. У него были такие то и такие то характеристики.

Потом ему добавились еще и "способности".

Это - **новая** сущность. Соответственно, она хранится либо в отдельной таблице, которая как то связана с существующими данными, либо - она хранится вместе с существующими данными, в отдельных **дополнительных** полях.

Учитывая всё это, мне кажется, если правильно сделать обновление - то у всех персонажей сохранятся все их характеристики, и просто добавятся новые.

И тут мы подходим к главному вопросу: *как это сделать?*

В общем, нужно понять, что происходит при обновлении.

В современных фреймворках обновления базы данных называются "миграциями". "Миграция", если убрать *щепотку магической составляющей* из этого названия - это SQL скрипт, описывающий переход базы данных из "состояния 1" в "состояние 2" *и обратно*. Благодаря последнему слову - миграцию можно "накатить" и "откатить". При этом старые данные - не страдают, остаются на месте.

У Вас, скорее всего, если разобраться, частью процесса обновления является обновление базы данных. При этом, скорее всего, в таблицу характеристик персоонажа просто должны добавиться поля. Для этого в SQL обычно используется команда `ALTER TABLE`, например,

`` ALTER TABLE `characters` ADD  `base_class` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ``

Это выражение описывает добавление в существующую таблицу одного единственного поля, без изменения данных в других полях

При таком подходе Вам не нужно будет заново как то UPDATE'ами устанавливать прежний уровень персоонажей.

Но если у Вас в процессе накатывания патчика происходит уничтоже ние старой таблицы и создание новой - при этом, конечно, данные будут удалены. Но такого не должно быть - ну, кто же делает такие патчи?

Осталось разобраться, чем "старая" таблица отличается от "новой". Если это не написано в явном виде - можно просто поставить эксперимент: не на боевом, а на тестовом сервере сделать "патч обновления" любым способом, и потом сравнить получившиеся таблицы.

Comment: При чем тут "Это - новая сущность". Я уже давно реализовал способности, как новую сущность. Но их можно улучшать, с повышением уровней. Они вкачиваются от очков способностей. Которые даются каждые 2 штуки, за один уровень. Есть персонажи 60 уровня. Можно в поле вписать сразу 120 очков. Есть другие, 40, 30 и т.д. Но самих зарегистрированных персонажей выше 9 тыс. Вручную, не ас... Вот я и прошу, может формула есть какая нибудь? Или может на C# Dapper использовать, получить список всех игроков. Потом умножить их уровни на 2 и мы получим очки способностей. И обновить через Update таблицу

Comment: Да, в той формулировке, в которой Вы это написали в комментарии-это действительно делается одним update